# How to add label to collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, label, constraints

I want to display a label if there is no post available on a users profile. I have copied a piece of code of an answer on here which is

```swift
   func setEmptyMessage(_ message: String) {
        let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 30))

        messageLabel.text = message
        messageLabel.textColor = .black
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
        messageLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
        messageLabel.sizeToFit()
        messageLabel.clipsToBounds = true

        self.collectionView.backgroundView = messageLabel
    }

    func restore() {
         self.collectionView.backgroundView = nil
    }
```

In use

```swift
    // Return users uploaded posts
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if posts.count == 0 {
            self.setEmptyMessage("No Posts")
        } else {
            self.restore()
        }
        return posts.count 
    }
```

The Code works great, the label displays when it needs to. The only problem is I have a collection view header and when I pull down to refresh   the view of the header mixes with the label. How can I either hide the label when I pull down to refresh or somehow give it a fixed constraint under the section header? Not sure if it would be better to hide the label when I pull down to refresh but I do not know how to grab the code for the emptyMessage and incorporate it with my handleRefresh code..

```swift
   @objc func handleRefresh() {

        posts.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        self.currentKey = nil
        fetchPosts()
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
```

Here are two screenshots of what I mean. First photo is where I want the label to stay.

[image]

**Second Photo** As you can see when I pull down to refresh the label will not stay in place. It kinda goes up with the header. Is this because I have set the message to be apart of the background view?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var messageLabel: UILabel?
func setEmptyMessage(_ message: String) {
    let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:view.frame.width, height: 30)) 

    messageLabel?.text = message
    messageLabel?.textColor = .black
    messageLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    messageLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    messageLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
    messageLabel?.sizeToFit()
    messageLabel?.clipsToBounds = true
    if let messageLabel = messageLabel {
        self.collectionView.backgroundView.addSubview(messageLabel)
        messageLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(..collectionView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(..collectionView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(..collectionView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

func restore() {
   messageLabel?.removeFromSuperView()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Best one for me.

Comment: your welcome, i'm glad to it helps. As an addition, you may create and add label then you may hide or show for performance etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you add screenshots, I understand what you mean.

The backgroundView won't follow the scrolling, so you won't get the effect you want.

I suggest you add a new cell type, this cell can be used as a hint tag, probably like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if something { // Replace with your judgment logic
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NoPostCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
       cell.label.text = "No Posts"
       return cell
    }

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.label.text = title

    return cell
}
```

#### Note:

The judgment here no longer uses `posts.count == 0` , it may never enter `cellForItemAt`

At this time I suggest you have two data structures, a normal data, which may be an array. Another array containing only one string, mainly showing `No Posts`. Judging conditions can be judged according to the data type

Comment: No I would like the header to stay the same. I've added two screenshots that I hope will help. Its just the label I would like to somehow have in the middle of the collection view

Comment: Sorry, I am late, and I am the same as `Gábor Hertelendy`.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an empltyCell for when posts are empty to be displayed:

For the number of items:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if posts.count == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return.posts.count
    } 
}
```

For the item at indexpath:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard !posts.isEmpty else {
        let emptyCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "emptyCell", for: indexPath) as! EmptyCell
        return emptyCell
    }
//... rest of your cellForItemAt code here
}
```

The cell class definition below:

```
class EmptyCell:UICollectionViewCell {

let label = UILabel()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    label.text = "No Posts yet"
    label.textAlignment = .center

    addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    backgroundColor = .clear
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError()
}
}
```

Also don't forget to register this cell for the collectionView in viewDidLoad():

```
self.collectionView!.register(EmptyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "emptyCell")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add leading and trailing constraints to 0 like:

```
lable.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))            
    lable.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

and set alignment of label to centre like:

```
label.textAlignment = .center;
```

And you will get the results.

Comment: I get reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'   Do I place the code in the function or some where else?

Comment: Sorry I'm late on this, is the mainView the collection view or UIview?

Comment: Do you mind just writing the code in a function so I can see it all together.